# Reverse URL mapping with AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine

I was wondering if there's a function like Django's `django.core.urlresolvers.reverse` for Google's App Engine. I've been searching everywhere but haven't been able to find anything about it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

If you use [webapp2](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/index.html), "a lightweight Python web framework compatible with Google App Engine’s webapp," you can take advantage of their [URI routing features](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html), which include a function `uri_for()` that does reverse routing akin to Django's `reverse()`.

webapp2 is essentially a superset of webapp, so it's trivial to drop in as a replacement. It's a pretty sweet little library.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really anything App Engine specific - if you're using [App Engine Patch](http://code.google.com/p/app-engine-patch/), you can use Django, including its URL resolvers. Alternately, you can use any other framework with a reverse resolver, or [use one on its own](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/01/Webapps-on-App-Engine-part-1-Routing).

Answer (score 2):

After a hard search, I found confusing [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/running.html#URL_Mappings) for similar functionality in Google App Engine's default webapp.WSGIApplication class.  It seems as though regular expressions can be passed to a Handler, but they're named and used by giving extra arguments to that handler's **get** function.